# How to update every value of the keyset in a LinkedHashMap in Scala, having a LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]?

Tags: scala, list, linkedhashmap, listbuffer, mutablemap

I have a LinkedHashMap of type:

```
var map: LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]] = ((1 -> (2, 1)), (2 -> 2), (3 -> (5, 3)))
```

I want to add an element to every list of every key, let's say i want to add "6" in order to have:

```
((1 -> (6, 2, 1)), (2 -> (6, 2)), (3 -> (6, 5, 3)))
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
val map: mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]] =
  mutable.LinkedHashMap(1 -> ListBuffer(2, 1),
                        2 -> ListBuffer(2, 2),
                        3 -> ListBuffer(5, 3))

val res = map.mapValues(lstBuffer => lstBuffer += 6)
println(res)
```

Yields:

```
Map(1 -> ListBuffer(2, 1, 6), 2 -> ListBuffer(2, 2, 6), 3 -> ListBuffer(5, 3, 6))
```

Note that `mapValues` is lazy and won't execute unless materialized. If we want to make this strict and execute immediately, we can use `map`:

```
val res = map.map { case (_, lstBuffer) => lstBuffer += 6 }
```

If you want to *prepend*, use `.prepend` instead (which returns Unit and is side effecting on the current `Map` instance):

```
map.foreach { case (_, lstBuffer) => lstBuffer.prepend(6) }
```

I want to note that usually, if you want to iterate the entire `Map[K, V]` sequentially, it's a sign you're using the wrong data structure. Although without more information I can't really establish a basis for that hypothesis.

Comment: Isn't `mapValues` lazy and you are executing side effects each time you print values?

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov `mapValues` is lazy, and `foreach` is the one materializing the result. Added a comment and an alternative strict solution. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: What data structure should i use? I will apply it to lists of hundreds of elements. I choose `LinkedHashMap` 'cause it uses a hash table. Also, isn't it possible to add the element at the head of each list?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov mapValues is not memoizing, IIRC, so if you print twice, you get side effects executed twice. Better just use `foreach`

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov It isn't. Better use `map` if the overall execution needs to happen immediately.

Comment: @Andrea It is possible, use `lstBuffer.prepend(6)` instead.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  
I just found out there is a mutable.HashTable class, but i can't see any example on the internet. Can you tell me how to even put keys and values into it? :(

Comment: Why do you need to use `mutable.HashTable`?

Comment: My purpose is to implement a hash table, with a constant time in research and delete operations @YuvalItzchakov